# Words should remain entact when "resize column → fit to data" is done

Tags: google-sheets, resize, width

When I do "resize column → fit to data" then this action doesn't align the words as required. The words break into parts. For example, a cell has this content : "cash back maximum". Each word is in an individual line within that cell. So there are 3 lines. Something like this :

cash

back

maximum

But after I do "resize column - fit to data" the cell content becomes "cash back maximu m". The last letter "m" breaks apart and moves down & now there are 4 lines. Something like this :

cash

back

maximu

m

How do I avoid this? I want words to remain entact. "Maximum" shouldn't break into "maximu" & "m". Ofcourse I can manually adjust column width to make the word entact / whole again but I wish there was a quick automatic command or formula or shortcut to do this.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation from `maximum` to `maximu` + `m`. Can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue?

Comment: one way I found to counter it is to resize column manually to fit the word + some extra space after the word and then do "fit to data" thingy

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem as described either. It works fine for me no matter how I do it (having tried four different methods. Is it possible that you've actually got a hidden character in there somewhere? Try widening the column in question, deleting the word maximum and typing it in again manually, then repeating the actions to **Resize column > Fit to data**. In addition, does this happen if you select the column(s), hover over the divider between cells to the right of the column letter until the cursor becomes a two-headed arrow, and then double-click?

Comment: @ErikTyler please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70555950/words-should-remain-entact-when-resize-column-%e2%86%92-fit-to-data-is-done/70559070#70559070) for screenshots.

Comment: Thank you @ErikTyler for this input. I am aware of this method. This method however gives a rough width. Hope you understand. It is a manual adjustment which is not what I am looking for. Yes manual adjustment as you suggested is a solution but "Resize column - fit to data" is the method which is expected to provide an automatic and precise width as per the contents of each and every cell in that particular column. It'd be better if it worked. But at present, unfortunately, "resize column fit to data" breaks the texts into pieces.

Comment: Thank you @player0 but the method you suggested creates a different result. This method instead makes almost the entire word(s) hide which I'm afraid is even more unhelpful.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike "cash back maximum" is in the header cell of the column in consideration. In this column are several financial numbers eg ₹41.8, ₹120.2, etc. The "resize column fit to data" action is supposed to adjust the width of this column precisely and optimally but instead it breaks the words into pieces. In my case the 3rd word (viz. maximum) in the header cell breaks into "maximu" and "m" ie "m" moves down below "maximu" as you can see in the screenshots thoughtfuly provided by taylor.2317

Comment: Are you sure you are quickly *double-clicking* the border to the right of the column letter at the top of the column, not merely single-clicking and dragging it?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Image 1]
This should be what it currently looks like for you.

[image: Image 2]
You can drag the cell "border" to increase the width, to allow all text to fit.

[image: Image 3]
You can double click a "border" to get it to fit to the longest text.